# Expo usePermissions infinite loop when using multiple permissions (array format)

Tags: react-native, expo

**Re.** https://github.com/byCedric/use-expo/blob/main/packages/permissions/docs/use-permissions.md

**Description of the bug:**
Component keeps re-rendering infinitely when I use multiple permissions syntax i.e.

```
const [permission, askForPermission] = usePermissions([Permissions.CAMERA, Permissions.LOCATION] );
```

**To Reproduce:**
Here is the snack link: https://snack.expo.io/@rabiarashid/shallow-pastry
I added a console.log statement and you will see that it prints infinitely